# IIB Collector node esql

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am using a collector node on IIB to collect a set of messages. Can someone help with sample ESQL after collector node to process a message collection? Since I am new to ESQL I am struggling to figure it out. The IBM info center is not very helpful on ESQL message collection.

Answer (score 0):

The code would depend on what you want to do with the collection.  If you want to loop through the collected messages, you could do something like this:

```
--reference the first message, the CollectionName is the first element in the array
DECLARE ref REFERENCE TO InputRoot.Collection.[2];

WHILE LASTMOVE(ref) DO
--reference the data like normal, domain is a header, parsers, etc.
SET Environment.Variables.data = ref.domain.data;
--example ref.XMLNSC.HTML.Body.h1
--do any other work on the message here
MOVE ref NEXTSIBLING;
END WHILE;
```

This loop will run until it reaches the end of the collection.  Then the MOVE command will return null and the LASTMOVE will return false.

Use a Trace node before the ESQL with the pattern ${Root} to see what the message structure looks like.  This is the best place to start to develop the ESQL you need to process the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am trying to merge all the message collected by collector to 1 single message. Say if there are six messages collected by collector am trying to merge that into 1 single message.

Comment: You would use the same as above, replace Environment.Variables.data with OutputRoot._parserName_._path_.  For example, `SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Body.Reply = OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Body.Reply || ref.XMLNSC.response;`
To get a new element for each message (array of replies) on the output, use `CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Body TYPE NameValue Name 'Reply' Value ref.XMLNSC.response;`